# Is it possible to Customise BackOffice

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I'm just trying to start out on Umbraco 7 with a view to sticking to the MVC route as much as possible. I've noticed that this has a completely different backoffice to the WebForms route and it looks quite nice.

However, I'd really like to be able to modify the back office. Partically the things I'd like to do are:

- Change the appearance (modifying the HTML and CSS)
- Add additional pages

I can't seem to find anything that explains how to do this for v7 of Umbraco. So the first question is, is it even possible to achieve this?

If so how do I go about doing so? I've adding Umbraco V7 as a nuget package so don't have any of the backend files by default (assuming they're compiled into the DLL's). So how would I go about making these modifications to anything existing or registering new pages?

Answer (score 0):

Great site about customizing  BackOffice - http://www.nibble.be/?p=454.
You can do whatever you want with Umbraco.